# Update of Android studio from 2.3.3 to 3.2. ERRORS

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I recently updated my Android Studio from 2.3.3 to 3.2 but unfortunately it have been two days, that I'm trying to fix bugs but, I resolved the most but I still have some problems that persist in my projects:

1. The gradle build keep showing me this error about Kotlin version:

   The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version
   1.2.51 and higher. Project 'XXX' is using version 1.1.4-3.

   => The problem is my kotlin is declared as automated update version :

   ```
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
   ```

   I don't know where can I change the version as they mention.
2. This line code is always underlined in red:

   `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

   The build tool version is 28.0.2

   The error declared is:

   > all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification.

PS: I used 28.0.0 is all com.android.support libraries.

If you have any solutions to this two problems please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ameerhamza6733.directmessagesaveandrepost"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 32
    versionName "1.0.32"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

implementation project(':easy_sharedpreference_library')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.github.lolucosmin:PermissionsWrapper:version_1.2'
implementation 'com.artjimlop:altex-image-downloader:0.0.4'
implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'

implementation 'com.webianks.library:easy-feedback:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation project(':library')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()

}
```

Comment: Share all your dependencies , it seems that some mixing version in support libraries is happen , also you can use this command to see dependecy tree : `gradlew app:dependencies`

Comment: *I don't know where can I change the version as they mention.* - in the build.gradle file in the root dir

Comment: post your dependencies from **app level** `build.gradle` code for second issue.

Comment: Jeel Vankhede, I did put the build.gradle file please check if everything inside it is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The gradle build keep showing me this error about Kotlin version:

Answer

1. Open your **project level** build.gradle file,
2. there you'll find a block named **`buildscript`**.
3. Go to that block and find if there is a variable named `ext.kotlin_version`
4. Change it to your latest version of **Kotlin** plugin.

---

> all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification.

Issue for this is that the library you're using [easy-feedback](https://github.com/webianks/EasyFeedback/blob/master/easy-feedback/build.gradle) is having different version for support library **(v25)** than you're using **(v28)**.

Solution is to exclude your support library from that dependency like below:

```
implementation ('com.webianks.library:easy-feedback:1.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
```

***Note :*** If problem still persist, then check it with other 3rd party dependencies too.

Comment: I don't have that block!

Comment: Every project does, i mentioned that go to project level. not app level

Comment: this is half an answer. What about the other issue?